# Does Wordpress list all pages for crawlers?

Tags: wordpress

I created a page on a Wordpress site that was for internal use only and triggers some backend code. Within a few days I started seeing hits on that page from "bingbot".

I'm not using any kind of sitemap plugin. How are crawlers finding this page?

I know the robots.txt file can block them but I want to make sure they don't show up for crawlers that don't respect this. I still want to have the page publicly accessible if someone types in the URL.

What needs to be done in Wordpress to make sure a page can't be discovered except by typing in the URL?

Comment: Probably better asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Any given URL is potentially "discovered" once the post is published and if there's a link to it from elsewhere on your site. There's no guaranteed way to prevent search engines from indexing a URL.

Comment: It's not linked from anywhere.